# Run Telegram iOS project with Xcode 15 error

Tags: ios, swift, telegram, xcode15

I am running Telegram ios project with its construction but when I hit the run button I get this error
can anybody help me?

`Could not parse Swift versions from: Swift/ErrorType.swift:200: Fatal error: Error raised at top level: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “swiftc” doesn’t exist." UserInfo={NSFilePath=swiftc}`[image]